# Entity framework mapping stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-6

In entity framework code first you can map your insert, update and delete stored procedures. Likewise how can I map a select stored procedure to an entity using the model builder?

Comment: You're doing code-first or model-first? Model-first creates a proxy for the stored procedure when you update your EDMX model from your database  AFAIK.

Comment: In the modelbuilder, you should be to specify a stored procedure for select/create/update/delete in the properties of the selected entity

Comment: @Schwarzie2478 there is no select

Comment: The need  to map a `select` stored procedure it's usually a signal that your database design is not really compatible with EF because you probably have to collect fields from different tables (something more complex that inheritance) to obtain an entity. If that's the case, one workaround is to create a `view` and map EF to this instead of stored procedures.